# Correct Use Case in S/W requirements

Tags: requirements, software, diagrams, use-case

So in S/W Requirements how to know a correct use case ?

for Example :
[image: this one here seems wrong but I'm not sure]

this one here seems **wrong** but *I'm* *not* *sure*

Answer (score 2):

It is completely wrong. `Log in` is no use case at all! It does not add any value to the actor. And that's what a UC basically shall show.

If it were a correct UC, the `<<includes>>` are the wrong way around.

To make it correct, remove `Log in` and connect the other UCs directly to the actor.

You can add constraints to the UCs that tell `{ actor must be logged in }`.

Comment: but what if we put 'Sign up'  instead of 'log in' ??

Comment: This is just another word for log in. Where is the added value?

Comment: I mean when the actor active the program for the first time doesn't he need an account ? just like signing up in an app or a website. because he the program will update the data-base with new data

Comment: In that case `Sign up` is a UC of it's own (creates an account). But you still can not replace it in the bubble above. It would be an extra bubble.

Comment: I see. So the UC would look like this [ One Actor : two vectors indicate sign up and add reports  bubbles the add reports bubbles will have three vectors indicates add Monthly , add Weekly , add Daily. I done it like that with all of my UC's so it will cover all the values that will be added to the user  ]

Comment: You can do so. But you should avoid include/extend since they are usually a sign for functional decomposition. And that'a definitely not the point in UC synthesis.

Comment: I got it now                                                                                                   System.out.println("Thank you very Much for ur Help" + "♥ ♥");